# Calling images from sqlite to ViewFlipper

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm making an app for my school project which is basically a wattage calculator for home appliances. I have about 50 75X75 icons of the appliances in my `ViewFlipper`. Is there a way to create a search interface to call these images rather than flipping through all images to find it? I went through couple of web sites and learnt that in order to use a search interface I need to store my images in a database. How it really works? Is there another way to do it? Or is it really possible to do it?

Comment: Anybody? I still couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you understand by a search interface. One option is to use a [`Gallery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) instead of your current `ViewFlipper`([Here is a real simple tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) that you could  use in your app). The `Gallery` widget will let the user to move quickly to the desired image by simple scrolling the `Gallery`(another advantage is that the user sees the images as it scrolls).

Also, instead of the `ViewFlipper` you could use a `Spinner` + one `ImageView`. The `Spinner`([Here is a tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html)) will let the user pick a name of an appliance and when this happens you will find the position of the user choice(from the `Spinner` and map that to a `HashMap`(that has as keys the position in the `Spinner` and as values the ids of the images)) and update the `ImageView` with the correct appliance image.

There are other ways but those are more complex to implement.